# esvect with transparency makes part of the arrow darker

Tags: arrows, transparency, vector

When using the `esvect` package in a transparency context, one can see that the arrow is built by superposing two "blocks": a line and an arrowhead. But as the line overrides the arrow head, the center of the arrow looks less transparent.

Is there a way to change this modifying `esvect` code?

[image: Transparency issue]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[semitransparent] {$\vv{v}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I open with evince or okular I can see what you mean, but with adobe reader all is perfectly rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something of a work-around for your specific example (I don't know if that was just the simplest way to get the arrow semi-transparent or if that is your actual use-case).  The work-around is to use `transparency group`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[transparency group,semitransparent]
  \node {$\vv{v}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: transparent arrow]

If you look closely, you can still see the effect in that the line is slightly thicker where the two pieces overlap, but it is much less evident that the transparency difference.

Comment: I don't know if I'll be able to use this workaround in every situation if I need to add a `scope`. I need to look at the doc to see what it is said about `transparency group` (a key I did not remember BTW `:)`)

Comment: BTW what setting did you use to get the big picture unpixellized?

Comment: I suppose one could define code to automatically put every node in a scope - there's code to do it with layers lying around on this site.  For the picture, I took a screenshot - I keep trying with the settings for `convert` but I can never remember the right invocation.

Comment: Ok. It works for me. Thanks. And the screenshot is a good tip `:)`